# How do I access STL classes like std::string in gdb postmortem?

Tags: gdb, stdstring, coredump

I have a core dump with a `std::string` that I'd like to inspect in gdb. Printing it gives me its contents as a null-terminated string, but how do I access other `std::string` properties such as size and capacity? Trying to access `s.size()` directly results in an error, "You can't do that without a process to debug."

Comment: The question this got duped to has a really outdated answer. The real answer is https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Comment: @EmployedRussian - In my case, the GDB STL support didn't tell me everything I needed to know (string size and capacity, vector elements past a certain number, etc.).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, disable any pretty-printers to see the raw member variables of the structure you're trying to print.

```
(gdb) disable pretty-printer
```

For many STL classes, their members are (hopefully) not too hard to figure out. For example, printing a `std::vector` with pretty-printing disabled gives output similar to the following:

```
$2 = {, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >> = {
    _M_impl = {, std::allocator > >> = {, std::allocator > >> = {}, }, _M_start = 0x804b028, _M_finish = 0x804b02c,
      _M_end_of_storage = 0x804b02c}}, }
```

Since the member variables are `_M_impl._M_start`, `_M_impl._M_finish`, and `_M_impl._M_end_of_storage`, you can use them as follows for a vector v:

- element 0 - `_M_impl._M_start[0]`
- size - `v._M_impl._M_end - v._M_impl._M_start`
- capacity - `v._M_impl._M_end_of_storage - v._M_impl._M_start`

std::string in particular is harder. [libstdc++'s implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h?revision=220758&view=markup#l2466) shows that the capacity, size, and reference count are stored before the beginning of the string, in a `std::basic_string::_Rep` structure, and gdb has trouble resolving this structure, so I had to resort to pointer arithmetic hacks. Here's how to do it for a string `s` in a 32-bit x86 app with the pre-C++11 ABI; other platforms may differ.

- reference count - `((int*)s._M_dataplus._M_p)[-1]`
- capacity - `((int*)s._M_dataplus._M_p)[-2]`
- size - `((int*)s._M_dataplus._M_p)[-3]`